# I am trying to install wine but accidentally installed the wrong version

Tags: package-management, wine, dependencies

i am trying to install wine and accidentally typed

```
sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources
```

which is for ubuntu version 22.04 jammy jellyfish. I am currently running 20.04 Focal Fossa.
Now when i type

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

it gives me the error

> eading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 8.0.2~jammy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

anyone know how to fix this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: You can delete this repository from `Software & Sources`, and then add the correct repository

Comment: Thanks for your reply how to i go about deleting a repository and adding one. sorry if this is simple but i dont have much expirience

Comment: Open the program called  Software & Sources. You will find the list of all the repositories you have added in the "Other Repositories" tab. There, find the Wine repository and delete it. Afterwards, run `sudo apt update`, and install wine from the terminal

Comment: I deleted the repository from the Software and Updates app then when i use 'sudo apt update' this shows up 'Hit:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:10 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease'

Comment: A compatible version of Wine is already available from the Software Center. Mucking about with cryptic install commands and "sources" and other faff that you don't understand is needless. Get out of the habit of looking at the internet for software until you have enough skill to do so safely.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ && ls`